# Need help catching an exception

Tags: java, generics, exception

I am creating a generic `Pair` class intended for use with integers.

Exception class:

```
public class WrongThing extends Exception{
    public WrongThing(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Pair<E> implements Comparable<E>{
    private E var1;
    private E var2;
    public Pair(E var1, E var2) throws WrongThing{
        //this is on purpose!!!
        System.out.println("var1 and var2 are switched");
        this.var1 = var2;
        this.var2 = var1;
    }

    void get(){
        System.out.println("the first actualy 2nd: "+
                var1 + "the ");
                System.out.println("  second actualy first" + var2);
    }

    void set1(E temp){
        System.out.println("var1 and var2 are switched");
        temp = var1;
    }

    void set2(E temp){
        System.out.println("var1 and var2 are switched");
        temp = var2;
    }

    E smallest(E var1, E var2){

        return var1;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Test case

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class PairTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws WrongThing{
        System.out.println("two integers please");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Pair<Integer> newPair;
        Pair<Integer> tempPair1= new Pair<Integer>(3,2);

        try{
            newPair = new Pair<Integer>(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt());
            //throw new InputMismatchException("that is not an Integer....");
        }catch(WrongThing exception){
            //System.out.println("you cant do that. try again and press enter after the first integer");
            newPair = new Pair<Integer>(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt());
            newPair.get();

        }
        finally{


        }
    }
    //newPair = new Pair<Integer>(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt());
}
```

When I run this code I get an `InputMismatchException`. Did I not create my exception correctly or not catching it when it is thrown?

Comment: I've remove the Eclipse tag, because this problem is unrelated to which IDE you use: it's a "pure" Java problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, it looks like you're only trying to catch a `WrongThing` Exception, not a `InputMismatchEception`.

```
try{
    // ...
}catch(WrongThing exception){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WrongThing is your custom exception. When necessary you need to throw it and catch it.

```
try{
    // throw new WrongThing("wrong thing");
}catch(WrongThing e1){
    // ...
}catch(InputMismatchException e2){
    // ...
}
```

`InputMismatchException` is thrown from [sc.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method `if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range`. So you need to cach it too.

Answer (score 0):

For the Scanner class you have to follow the process hasNext() -> next()

You wont get any exception in this way.

```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);       
          while (sc.hasNext()) {

                 if(sc.hasNextInt())
                System.out.println(sc.nextInt());

              sc.next();
          }
         sc.close();
```

Another thing is to have a cascade of exception blocks with `catch(Exception e)` at the bottom to be sure to catch all the exceptions.

```
   try{
         // code which throws checked exceptions.
        }catch(WrongThing e1){      
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e2){
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
           // cleanup
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `java.util.InputMismatchException` says:

> Thrown by a `Scanner` to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

The one for `Scanner.nextInt()` says:

> Throws: `InputMismatchException` - if the next token does not match the `Integer` regular expression, or is out of range

Basically the exception is being thrown from `Scanner.nextInt()` when you type something in the console that is not an integer. When that happens, the constructor `new Pair<Integer>(...)` won't even be called, so any check you put it in the constructor becomes useless.

What you need to do is

```
newPair = null;
while (newPair == null) {
    try {
        newPair = new Pair<Integer>(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt());
    } catch(InputMismatchException exception){
        System.out.println("you cant do that. try again and press enter after the first");              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create object of pair class

```
Pair newPair = new Pair<Integer>(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt());
```

It can only throw  Custom Exception as you have mentioned this type of Exception in your class. `sc.nextInt()` expects Integer type of Input from the console and when any other character is passed it throws `InputMismatchException`. So you also need to catch InputMismatch Exception like

```
try{
    // throw new WrongThing("wrong thing");
}catch(WrongThing e1){
    // ...
}catch(InputMismatchException e2){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scanner is throwing InputMismatchException which you are not handling. [InputMismatchException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) is a RuntimeException so you do not need to explicitly catch it. (usually tese are programmer errors) If you are using Java 7 then you can use this syntax ([multicatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)) to deal with more than one exception

```
try{
....
}
catch(WrongThing|InputMismatchException e1){
        //deal with exception.
}
```

This assumes that you want to do deal with both exceptions in the same way. If you dont then I would advice splitting them up as other answers have done for clarity.